# MySQL selecting string with special characters

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I'm having a problem selecting strings from database. The problem is if you have `McDonald's` in row and if you are searching with a string `mcdonalds` it wouldn't find any results. Any suggestions?

I forgot to mention that I'm using `LIKE` in `WHERE` sentence.

Comment: Search for the correct term. If you search for "Joe" you won't find "Jane", so why the surprise? (Also, you should really never have too much McDonald's in a row.)

Comment: How are you searching? Straight equality using `row = 'mcdonalds'`?

Comment: I'm using LIKE right now, but is not working as you can see.
LIKE row '%$string%'

Comment: I suppose that `row like "mcdonald%"` won't cur it for you?

Comment: Imagine searching for McDonald's with a mcdonalds string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your search requirements are to ignore certain characters, you can remove them during a search by `replace`ing them with a blank.

This answer solves your problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM restaurants
WHERE replace(name, '''', '') like '%mcdonalds%'; -- This will match "McDonald's"
```

FYI, a single quote literal (`'`) is written as a doubled single quote (`''`), so to specify a single quote as a parameter to `replace` you need four quotes in a row (`''''`) - two at each end and the doubled quote in the middle for the actual quote.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the LIKE operator:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

EDIT:

I tried this a lot of different ways and my only recommendation is to use whatever code you might have that is sending the query to first add '\' escape to the appropriate characters. PHP does this well:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

...but that is just guessing at the full context of the situation.

Comment: Don't understand the downvote. OP didn't state that he/she was already using like. Compensating with upvote.

Comment: Its not question of input, but about a mysql function. Something like TRIM function, but insted of removing spaces I would like to remove some special chars (')