# mysql query special characters

Tags: mysql, special-characters

What is the query to determine character set of the MySQL Database ? Or is there a way to determine it.

How to query special characters (non-UTF8) characters from a column ?

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE column .....
```

Comment: This might help you [Mysql Selecting String with Special Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603132/mysql-selecting-string-with-special-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a question related to this question..

Heres a link to another question here in stackoverflow that can give you hints or tricks How to see what character set a database / table / column is in MySQL? [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-database-table-column-is-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a direct way with `regex` which didnt work much. The other solution that i found is this:

```
select * from tablename
where columnname regexp(concat('[',char(128),'-',char(255),']'));
```

As for the character set you can use

```
select DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```