# Mysql like statement with special characters in column table not able to search

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql a very normal like statement

```
$wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE \"%$s%\"
```

The table column data is "D.Y Patil" (without quotes)

When I search for text "dy patil" is doesn't come in the list?

Why the dot is making a mess, what should I do to make it better?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect it to match? `LIKE` requires everything to match exactly, except for `%` and `_` wildcards in the pattern.

Comment: `like '%...%'` is a braindead SIMPLE substring search. it can't handle things like `d.y` v.s. `dy`.

Comment: I want if there are any special characters in the table it should neglect that and search without it.@Barmar

Comment: @MarcB Yes i know that hence asked what should i do to make the mysql query like I want?

Comment: don't use `like` matches then. you could try `soundex()` comparisons, and/or `fulltext searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my solution, by using mysql statement `replace` .

**Here is my solution**

> SELECT * from table WHERE replace($wpdb->posts.post_title, '''', '')
>   LIKE \"%$s%\"

**Thanks to the post**

[MySQL selecting string with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603132/mysql-selecting-string-with-special-characters)